# Trouble with Eagle's BGA autorouter

Tags: eaglecad, bga, autorouter

Personally I'm having trouble with eagle's bgaAutoRouter when I use it, it's not doing the bga tracks and routes and I'm wasting a lot of time looking for how to make it work. my settings in image.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

DRILL = 0.05MM
ALT   = 0.125MM

layer = (1+2*15+16)

eagle version = 9.2.2

BGA STATUS = 0.0% do not leave that percentage

[datasheet](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/76/f9/c8/10/8a/33/4b/f0/DM00115714.pdf/files/DM00115714.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00115714.pdf) bga

where I'm wrong that I can not solve this puzzle ?

Comment: Which package are you using? There are two on the datasheet

Comment: UFBGA169-7X7MM STM32F429AIH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have 2mm minimum via diameter, if the datasheet recommends 0.2mm via diameter. Observe the recommendations in section 8.5.1 BGA 216 0.8mm Pitch Design Example below.

The autorouter will be failing because the rules are too strict to place tracks and vias. Routing is impossible without reducing the minimum via size, track width and reducing the clearances. Check with your PCB fab house on their capabilities.

[image]

[image]

Comment: how can I do it manually if I can use AutoRouter in eagle?

Comment: Here is a guide: https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/blog/routing-autorouting-pcb-layout-basics-2/